# how to send class pointer to python function?

Tags: python, c++

i have a c++ class A , it will callback a python function foo(A) , and i want to send a A* pointer to this function , how can i do it ?
my code is similar as follow :

```
PyObject* arg = (PyObject*)(pA);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, arg);
PyObject* pRet = PyObject_CallObject(foo, args);
```

but it always crash , seems wrap arg from A* is not correct , can anybody help me ?

Comment: You can’t just **pretend** your `A` object is a Python object!  The cast should be a red flag.  Moreover, what do you want the Python function to **do** with the pointer?

Comment: function foo is a python function , i callback it from C++ , in foo , the pointer will call some member function , such as A::do_something()

Comment: how to wrap the pointer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a C pointer around with the Python/C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436578/passing-a-c-pointer-around-with-the-python-c-api)

Comment: i already checked that question before , but it can't run correctly

Comment: Then it seems that you have a specific question in mind about it that you should ask.